# DataGridComboBoxColumn does not show list of values

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I want to populate a DataGridComboBoxColumn in `DataGrid` with status Values from a list of strings.

The XAML looks like this

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Status" >
  <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
      <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding}" />
    </Style>
  </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

The code for the string is a simple Generic list

```
var lstStrings = new List<string>();
lstStrings.Add("New");
lstStrings.Add("Open");
lstStrings.Add("ReOpen");
lstStrings.Add("Closed");

DataGridComboBoxColumn cmbx = grdComments.Columns[1] as DataGridComboBoxColumn;
cmbx.ItemsSource = lstStrings;
```

The Grid data is a list of Objects of a class. The problem is that the grid data status column value is blank by default (it is not showing the values already saved). When i click the cell the combo is showing with the values but when I select any value it is also not showing.

i hope my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: possible dublicate of this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8346869/920384

Comment: There is no code in that example so I am unable to connect the dots via only xaml

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing more code, but I am guessing either your `MyClass.Status` is not a string, or the binding is not correct. At what point is the ComboBox getting bound to your DataItem? I don't see it in the XAML anywhere. And where are you filling it's ItemsSource? I'm confused because you have a binding for `ItemsSource`, and it looks like you're setting it in code-behind

Comment: `cmbx` is the ComboBoxColumn and I m setting `List<string>` there when the window is loaded. I have updated the code also

Answer (score 0):

For data binding to work, XAML items must be bound to public properties of a class.
In the code example that you are giving it would appear that you are attempting to bind to a local variable.

I would suggest that you look at using an ObservableCollection type and implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your class, that way changes to the list made in code will automatically be updated on the view.

Comment: the list I am populating will be populated one time only do I need to make a class for just some static values? Besides the combo values are showing in the combo the only problem is in selection